# browser keeps crashing when i run my code

Tags: javascript, while-loop, three.js, crash

i have the following code:

```
var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg", "image5.jpg", "image6.jpg", "image7.jpg", "image8.jpg"];
var objects = [];
var geometry;

while(objects.length < images.length) {

        var imagesIndex = 0;
        var object = [

            texture1 = textureLoader.load( "data/"+ images[imagesIndex] ),
            material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture1 } ),
            objectMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material1 ),
            location3d = new THREE.Vector3( Math.random()* 500-250, Math.random()* 500-250, Math.random()* 500+120 )

        ];  


        var overlapping = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < objects.length; j++) {
            var projectCubeLoc = objects[j][0][3];
```

the var otherCubesLoc = projectCubeLoc[j]; generates the error

```
            var otherCubesLoc = projectCubeLoc[j];
            var distance = projectCubeLoc.distanceTo( otherCubesLoc );
            console.log(distance);

            if (distance < 150) {
                overlapping = true;
                break;
            };
        };
```

placed the statement outside of the for-loop because overlapping is false at least one object will be put in the array

```
        if (!overlapping) {
            objects.push(object);
            imagesIndex++;
        };
     };
```

but now i get TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

when i run this code in the browser the browser just crashes... i don't get any error messages the browser will just crash and quit it self...
i think it has something to do with the while loop but i cant figure out what is wrong...

any help or tips are greatly appreciated!

if there is more code needed or if you would like to see a jsfiddle just ask :)

Comment: When you start the loop, the `objects` array is empty. So your `for` loop never runs. Code inside of your `for` loop is the only thing that adds anything to the `objects` array. You've got yourself an infinite loop.

Comment: No javascript should ever make a browser crash and quit suddenly. There may be a bug in your code, but there is also a bug in your browser, and behavior will vary from browser to browser (so you should say which browser you are using). You could also try inserting alerts at various points in your code to find out how far it gets before it crashes the browser. Then you can try to work around the problematic line (and maybe file a bug report with the browser authors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg", "image5.jpg", "image6.jpg", "image7.jpg", "image8.jpg"];
var objects = [];

geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100,10,10 );

while(objects.length < images.length) {

    var imagesIndex = 0;

    var object = {};
    object.texture1 = textureLoader.load( "data/"+ images[imagesIndex] );
    object.material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: object.texture1 } );
    object.objectMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, object.material1 );
    object.location3d = new THREE.Vector3( Math.random()* 500-250, Math.random()* 500-250, Math.random()* 500+120 );

    var overlapping = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < objects.length; j++) {
        var projectCubeLoc = objects[j].location3d;
        var distance = projectCubeLoc.distanceTo( object.location3d );

        if (distance < 150) {
            overlapping = true;
            break;
        };
    };

    if (!overlapping) {
        objects.push(object);
        imagesIndex++;
        object.objectMesh.position = object.location3d;
        console.log(object.location3d);
        scene.add(object.objectMesh);
    };
};


console.log(objects);
```

i replaced the object array with a object called object. this way i could get the desired data out of the array from objects without having to deal with 0 of undefined errors. it works great now ;) thanks for all the help @Asad Jamil hope this will help anyone in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning anything to the objects array.

Your code never reaches your objects.push call in your for loop.

You initialize the array as empty, so when it gets to the for look `j == 0` and `objects.length == 0` so the loop doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are working with Unity3d but it happened to me once when I tried to execute such a code of C#.
    Actually you are declaring a variable inside the loop, and each time it updates it always sets the value of that variable to zero, making it a mesh.

Comment: i am working with a javascript libary called three.js

Comment: I am new to js and unaware of , for what this above mentioned library is used. But I have shared my personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

1. As the `while(objects.length < images.length)` loop start, you have
   empty array, which will pass initially, because this time length of
   the `objects` is less the images array.
2. As you going forwards, you have declare new variable `object`, which
   is supposed to be pushed or added in to the `objects` (My assumption
   as per the naming). and then you are  `for (var j = 0; j <objects.length; j++)` starting the for loop, which is using the
   length of `objects`, which is not being initialized yet. In the
   whole function. so it will never enter in the loop
3. if (!overlapping) {objects.push(object);imagesIndex++;}; this statement can not be reached because loop did not gonna be start.

No values are pushed into the `objects` array variable,which in turn going to the point 1 of the description and which will form a infinite loop in your function , in turn causes crashing of the browser.

**Description** : as fucntion start executing, 'objects' length is 0 and it's less the length of the image, which is a valid condition, but as fucntion executes the inner loop, that time the length of the variable 'objects' is also zero, as you did not add value in the object. that time objects.length is 0. so for loop did not execute and again goes to check while condition, at this time 'objects' length is also zero, valid scenario again execute the all line of code as I describe previous, still for loop is not going to tun because no values were added into the variable 'objects' before the execution of loop. and same scenario run upto infinite. hope this will clear all you doubts .

Comment: thank you for the explanation :) could you give me a solution? to give me more insight? i am quite new to programming in general... because i cant really figure this out myself :(

Comment: @FutureCake what you not able to understand ? can you describe ? on whcih part you want me to put light more ?

Comment: what do you mean by: you have empty array, which will pass initially, because this time length of the objects is less the images array. what do you exactly mean by pass initally?

Comment: ooh i think i got it! because the objects array is empty the for-loop never runs because the length = 0 that is why nothing gets added. and then you get an invinite loop because the while loop keeps trying and trying...  So how do i make it then that the first time an object gets added to the objects array?

Comment: exactly buddy . @FutureCake updated my answer for description you requested.

Comment: so do you maybe have a suggestion on how to fix this? :)

Comment: @FutureCake well !! for that being understand your requirement, need time. I am still looking for it!!

Comment: what if you push the object before the for loop, and did not change your function. just add objects.push(object)  line before the for loop ?

Comment: No don't do the above thing as I said @FutureCake

Comment: i think i figured it out (partially) see my updated question :)

Comment: @FutureCake what changes you have made ? and if it's solution then don't update your question as far I know?

Comment: i did some testing and i found the code added one object to the objects array but it didnt execute the for-loop on the second pass..

Comment: what do you mean by second pass? which line gives error ?

Comment: Js Fiddle is beterr I think @FutureCake

Comment: sure ill make one tomorrow thank you for all the help so far! :)